# ungrab_pointer() in Xlib doesn't exist but ungrab_button won't release the mouse

Tags: python, x11, python-2.x

I can't find a way to unregister my `grab_pointer`call with python-xlib.
If you don't un-grab you won't be able to click inside windows which is a annoying issue if you're used to it.

Aside from the code being ugly, the relevant parts are thse:

```
try:
    display.screen().root.grab_pointer(True, X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
    display.record_enable_context(ctx, handle_event)
    display.record_free_context(ctx)
except:
    display.record_disable_context(ctx)
    #display.screen().root.ungrab_pointer(X.CurrentTime)
    display.screen().root.ungrab_button(0, [0])
    display.flush()
    exit(1)
```

The first three lines grabs the pointer and will (with the rest of the code) output each and every event as I want it to. But whenever a issue or Ctrl+C event is raised The `except` block triggers (as expected).

The problem is that there's no `display.screen().root.ungrab_pointer` call aparently.
[Every code documented using this library says there should be](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Xlib.display.Display.ungrab_pointer), but I can't find one.

Any ideas how to ungrab the pointer?

**version**: 0.15-0.10.rc1.fc21

---

For the brave souls unlucky enough to want to help me, here's the full code:

```
import select

from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
from Xlib.ext import record
from Xlib.protocol import rq

def handle_event(event):
    print(event)

display = Display(':0')
ctx = display.record_create_context(
            0,
            [record.AllClients],
            [{
                    'core_requests': (0, 0),
                    'core_replies': (0, 0),
                    'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                    'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                    'delivered_events': (0, 0),
                    'device_events': (X.ButtonPressMask, X.ButtonReleaseMask),
                    'errors': (0, 0),
                    'client_started': False,
                    'client_died': False,
            }]
 )

try:
    display.screen().root.grab_pointer(True, X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
    display.record_enable_context(ctx, handle_event)
    display.record_free_context(ctx)
except:
    display.record_disable_context(ctx)
    #display.screen().root.ungrab_pointer(X.CurrentTime)
    display.screen().root.ungrab_button(0, [0])
    display.flush()
    exit(1)


try:
    while 1:
        # Wait for display to send something, or a timeout of one second
        readable, w, e = select.select([display], [], [], 1)

        # if no files are ready to be read, it's an timeout
        if not readable:
            print('Got no events')
            break

        # if display is readable, handle as many events as have been recieved
        elif display in readable:
            i = display.pending_events()
            while i > 0:
                event = display.next_event()
                handle_event(event)
                i = i - 1
except:
    display.record_disable_context(ctx)
    display,ungrab_pointer(X.CurrentTime)
    display.flush()
```

**Ps. I will make pretty functions and classes of this later, but first I need the logic to work so I understand it better. D.s**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ungrab_pointer` is a method of Display, not Window.

```
 display.ungrab_pointer(X.CurrentTime)
```

works.

C prototypes of the functions are:

```
int XGrabPointer(Display *display, Window grab_window, Bool owner_events, 
                 unsigned int event_mask, int pointer_mode, 
                 int keyboard_mode, Window confine_to, 
                 Cursor cursor, Time time);
int XUngrabPointer(Display *display, Time time);
```

The Python Xlib library is a more or less mechanical wrapper around Xlib. Functions that accept `Display*` and `Window` are generally mapped to methods of the `Window` class, functions that accept just `Display*` are mapped to methods of `Display`.

Comment: Quite sure I tried this, but you'll have an up vote for now and a resolution if it actually works. Will check in a bit!

Comment: Could swear I tried this, and I did. However I did `display,ungrab_pointer(X.CurrentTime)` <- Note the comma and not the dot. *sigh*